# how to concatenate parameters to link in mat-tab-nav-bar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a `mat-tab-nav-bar` to create two tabs in a component, namely:

1- basic-data

2- bill-money

When I click on first tab it sends id and isn to another tab using service and vise versa from second tab to first tab
this piece of code into container component (includes two tabs)
I want to put parameters(id & isn) beside this link
        link: 'basic-data'
how to concatenate them to 'basic-data'

```
this.navLinks = [
  {
    label: 'بيانات أساسية',
    link: 'basic-data',
    index: 0
},
     {
        label: 'مصروف فاتورة',
        link: 'bill-money',
        index: 1
    },        
];
```

this in routing.module

```
{
path: 'invoice', component: InvoiceComponent,
children: [
  { path: 'basic-data/:id/:isn', component: BasicDataComponent },
  { path: 'bill-money', component: BillMoneyComponent },
]  }
```

[UPDATE]
mat-tab-nav-bar in container component

```
<nav  mat-tab-nav-bar dir="rtl">
<div>
<a mat-tab-link
*ngFor="let link of navLinks"
[routerLink]="link.link"
routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
[active]="rla.isActive"
style="font-size: x-large;color: black"
>{{link.label}}
</a>
</div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. I got the first part but I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: I want to keep id & isn in the url when First tab loaded first time the url is invoice/basic-data/27/3490464 when click on second tab and click on first tab again id & isn is removed like that invoice/basic-data

Comment: I see now. Can you please post the part you use `mat-tab-nav-bar`.

Comment: I updated question with the part I use mat-tab-nav-bar

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As long as your variables for id and isn are already set, you can add them to a list in the link property for that item:

```
this.navLinks = [
  {
    label: 'بيانات أساسية',
    link: ['basic-data', id, isn],
    index: 0
},
     {
        label: 'مصروف فاتورة',
        link: 'bill-money',
        index: 1
    },        
];
```